# Managed/shared web hosting with PHP 5.3 +

Tags: php, joomla, hosting, web-hosting

Does anyone know of any hosting providers running PHP 5.3 + ?? We need this for our custom Joomla sites.

Comment: This would probably be better on Webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search for "shared hosting php 5.3" gives http://servergrove.com/index.php

Comment: Servergrove seems like only provider that gives you the option of running 5.2 OR 5.3- They look promising- give you chroot shell access and concentrate on PHP hosting

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to consider [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). I've started using VPS for about a year ago and I'm loving the freedom. It's a little bit tricky at the beginning but google is your friend :) Hope it helped some.

Comment: You're right, and I'm a fan of VPS as well for the obvious control benefits, but sometimes you just want managed hosting for the ease/security...

Answer (score 1):

I've also been spending a lot of time looking for an affordable shared hosting which provides php5.3 support. Hard to find.
Check out DreamHost.com, they offer 5.3 as a beta - I would go with that. Their service is better than others, and they give you more access (ssh for instance.)

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.  It's crazy how hard it is to find.

Answer (score 0):

one.com is also using 5.3 already.